# Edit a Microsoft Project file using Project for the Web

Tags: ms-project

We are a small team with one Project Manager and a few people working on projects. We would like to use Microsoft Project.

We would like to have a **Project Plan 3** for the PM in order to use the **Project Desktop Client** and a **Project Plan 1** for the team members, with just **Project for the web**. The team members will need to make some small changes to the project plan.

We setup a Project Web App SharePoint website and configured the desktop client to use that server. We are able to save and update the project from the desktop client to the server and we are able to see the project using the Project for the Web interface (https://project.microsoft.com).

Anyway, in the web interface we can see that the source file is different:

[image]

For instance:

- **testotesto** is the project created from the desktop client (Source: PWA Project)
- **Temp project** is the project created directly into the web platform (Source: Project)

If I click on the **testotesto** project using the Project for the Web platform, I'm redirected to the SharePoint website ([https://blabla.sharepoint.com/sites/yada/Project%20Detail%20Pages/ProjectDetails.aspx?ProjUid=[cut]](https://blabla.sharepoint.com/sites/yada/Project%20Detail%20Pages/ProjectDetails.aspx?ProjUid=%5Bcut%5D))

Is there any way to create a file from the desktop client and edit it using Project for the Web?

For reference, here you can find the Microsoft Project plans: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/project/compare-microsoft-project-management-software

Comment: Have you considered using a Git repo?

Comment: This could work if we all use the desktop version, but the guys with only the Project for the web will not be able to edit the plan. Or maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I researched this myself just today and have to disappoint you, it's not possible.

Microsoft says it [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/project-for-the-web-and-project-online-desktop-client-2dd7583c-eb34-467f-bf63-607bdc816e20):

> The Project Online desktop client doesn’t connect to Project for the
> web – as with all other future features, we will be evaluating this
> based on user feedback.

You can't even easily migrate existing PWA projects to Project for Web, as explained in the [comparison between Project Online and the new Project for the Web](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/project-for-the-web-and-project-online-6569170c-5c8e-474e-a7f0-642872f62f8a):

> At some point in the future we will be providing native migration
> tools to move project data from your existing Project Online
> environment to Project for the web.

Which should make it clear that it's currently out of the question to open PWA files with Project for the Web.

Quite a few milestones left for MS to achieve IMO. :)

Comment: What can I say if not "wow". That's a pity IMHO :)